# The named parameter children isnt defined

Tags: flutter

I get this curious error for following simple code:

> The named parameter children isnt defined.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: Center(
            children: <Widget>[
        Text('Hello World'),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: null,
              child: const Text('Disabled Button'),
            )
        ]),
      );
      }
}
```

Can anyone spot the mistake? I think I am blind...
Best Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Center` doesn't accept children, only child (one widget), you can add a `Column` inside your Center

```
  Center(
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Text('Hello World'),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: null,
          child: const Text('Disabled Button'),
        )
      ])
    ),
```